# how to use angular js and twig together

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony, twig

I followed a video tutorial on angular js very carefully and it was a pleasure. yet I have one concern: how to integrate (put together) angular js and twig on the same form as both have the same syntax display

Comment: See the link in my last comment for a few ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There is more way to solve you problem.

1. Embed angular's curly braces in a twig `{% verbatim %} {% endverbatim %}` statement each time you need to use Angular.  See [Verbatim tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html).
2. Change interpolation of Angular e.g.

> ```
> angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($interpolateProvider) {
>     $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');     
> });
> ```

3. Change twig delimiters

Comment: the answer is correct.thank you very much :)